# C++ making a while loop to give the sum of the operands and operators entered, end flag data type

Tags: c++, while-loop, switch-statement

I'm making a program that will ask the user to enter a number followed by a plus or minus sign and another number, etc..., until the user enters "=". The program is supposed to add or subtract all the inputs and present a final total as the output. My issue is, first of, I'm completely lost, secondly when I try to see if the input is "=", I get the following error
code:

```
lab3.cpp:14:20: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]
    while (input != "=")
```

I'm not sure what data type I need to use so that it can compare whether or not the input is "=". Also any general pointers on the multitude of things I'm doing wrong are greatly appreciated, Cheers!
Code below (and expected output for a better idea):

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>;
using namespace std;


int main()
{ 
   
   char plusMinus;
   int total = 0;
   int input;
   cout << "Welcome to your friendly neighborhood accumulator! Please input your expression, starting with an operand and type in  '='  when completed.";
   cin >> input;
   total = input;
   // I'm not sure how im supposed to see if the input is "=" and stop the loop
   while (input != "=")
    { 
     
      cin >> plusMinus;
      
      
      switch (plusMinus)
       {
          case '+': total = total + input; break;
          case '-': total = total - input; break; 
           
       }
      cin >> input;
    }
      cout << " The answer is " << total << endl;
   cout << " Thank you for using your friendly neighborhood accumulator"<< endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Welcome to your friendly neighborhood accumulator!
Please input your expression, starting with an operand and type in  '='  when completed.
3.0
+
2.0
-
-5.2
=
The answer is 10.2
```

Comment: `=` will not be valid input when inputting an integer.

Comment: @FredLarson Is there a data type that takes both characters and numbers so it can be compared?

Comment: I'd use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) with [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). Once you have determined the input is not `=`, use [`std::stoi()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) to make an integer out of it.

Comment: A common alternative is to read an `int` and test the stream immediately after (You should always test the stream state after every transaction anyway. The sooner you spot bad input, the easier it is to clean up the mess.). If the read failed, `clear` the error flags, read again with a `char` and compare the `char` against the valid tokens you can get. If the read still fails, the stream is broken or closed and requires smarter handling.

Comment: @FredLarson I made a mistake, it was supposed to be ` cin >> plusMinus` before the switch statement, I edited it. would you be able to give me an example on how to implement the `std::string`? I've never seen that before.

Comment: I suspected so. For an example, take a look at the example code on the `std::getline()` page I linked above. It's in the neighborhood of what you're trying to do.